# Mongodb: concat to existing document

Tags: mongodb, concatenation

I have my collection like this:

```
{
"_id" : "ID1234",
"read_object" : "sss-ssss",
"expireAt" : ISODate("2020-04-30T22:00:00.000Z")
}
```

In case he encounters the same ID, I would like to update the read_object field, otherwise create a new document.
I tried to do it like this:

```
db.collection.update(
{ _id: "ID1234" },
{
  $set: { read_object: { $concat: ["$read_object", "test"] } }, 
},
{ upsert: true }
)
```

but I get an error every time:

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'read_object.$concat' is not valid for storage.
```

If I add square brackets before $set, like this:

```
db.collection.update(
{ _id: "1b1b871493-14a0-4d21-bd74-086442df953c-2020-02" },
[{
  $set: { read_object: { $concat: ["$read_object", "test"] } }, 
}],
{ upsert: true }
)
```

I get this error:

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'read_object.$concat' is not valid for storage.
```

Where do I have a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) is an aggregation operator, meaning you can't use it while using the basic `update` syntax as you can only use update operators on it.

With that said Mongo version 4.2 introduces [pipeline updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2/#availability), which is basically what you're trying to do with the square brackets.

Assuming you are using Mongo version 4.2 heres a working example:

```
db.test1.update({_id: "ID1234"}, [
    {$set: {"read_object": {$concat: [{$ifNull: ["$read_object", ""]}, "test"]}}}
], {upsert: true});
```

Basically we just need to "replace" `read_object` if document does not exist as it is undefined in that case.

If you are using Mongo version that's smaller than 4.2 then unfortunately there is no way to do what you want in one operation, you'll have to first read the document and then adjust accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but as you wrote above, it's probably because I have the mongodb version 3.4.23

Comment: If you wanna play with that syntax mongo has test shell you can try: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/